# Android: library(SO File) for DatagramSocket().connect()

Tags: android, c++, udp

Before android-N if i create object of  `DatagramSocket()` and call `connect` function

```
clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
clientSocket.connect().
```

for lower level (library) this is calling  `connect` function `libjavacore.so` library.

but in Android-N I am not getting this connect call in  `libjavacore.so`
may someone help me to find the library for this.

Comment: Is it just a curiosity or your program relies on such internal details somehow?

Comment: I am working on android swizzling :)

Comment: ok done its is available inside  `libopenjdkjvm.so`